# Thread error while running NetBeans project

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a project to create a piechart

when I click on piechart button i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable
```

I used this jar file for the project: jfreechart-0.9.21.jar
Any help please?!

This is my code:

```
 private void pieChartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       DefaultPieDataset pieDataset=new DefaultPieDataset();
       pieDataset.setValue("first", new Integer(10) );
       pieDataset.setValue("second", new Integer(20) );
       pieDataset.setValue("third", new Integer(30) );
       pieDataset.setValue("fourth", new Integer(40) );
       JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("My Pie Chart", pieDataset, true, true, true);
       PiePlot p = (PiePlot)chart.getPlot();
     //  p.setForegroundAlpha(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
       ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Pie Chart!",chart);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setSize(450,500);
    }
```

Comment: did you add jar files ?

Comment: yes i did, jfreechart-0.9.21.jar

Comment: @ambeh obaid  not only jfreechart you have to add jcommon too

Comment: ok, i'll try this now and give you a feedback. thank u alot

Comment: i added this jar folder and the previous error gone, but there is a new error: 
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.ui.Spacer.getAdjustedHeight(D)D"

Comment: @ameneh obaid presumably your jfreechart version and jcommon version doesn't match

Comment: are you sure you added the right jar and all other dependencies needed?

Comment: I only added two jar files. 
the first is:  jfreechart-0.9.21.jar
and the second is: jcommon 
and the code is above, i don't know if there is other jar files i need

Comment: @amnehobaid what is your jcommon version ?

Comment: I downloaded it from here
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcommonjar.htm
the first one outside the table

Comment: @amnehobaid remove existing jcomman and try to add this http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/3.%20JCommon/Version%200.9.6/
or use new version of jfreechart your jfree version is too old

Comment: when i downloaded the version u send the error gone. thank you so much @getlost

Comment: @amnehobaid did you able get the chart?

Comment: yes the chart shown in the frame, but i realized that i have to draw the circle from the scratch in my project Lol. it's not allowed to use available methods in netbeans. this is what my teacher want me to do. draw a circle from the scratch :(